# Always operate at Time.timeScale = 1?

Tags: unity, c#

How do I make a specific script always operate at `Time.timeScale = 1` **no matter what**? I want it to override even when another script calls `Time.timeScale = 0` for example.

Comment: Why? It sounds like you may be taking a wrong approach somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't make use of rigidbody physics, just save a copy of the current timescale in a local variable and set Time.timeScale to 1 at the beginning of the method. At the end of the method, reset Time.timeScale to the backed up value.

```
void Update() {
     float oldTimeScale = Time.timeScale;
     Time.timeScale = 1.0f;

     // your code

     Time.timeScale = oldTimeScale;
}
```

Another caveat is that FixedUpdate will never be called when the time scale is 0.

You can also ditch Unity's timescale handling altogether and do your own by having an own timescale instance variable in every MonoBehavior and multiply it with Time.deltaTime whenever you use it. Again, this will not work with rigidbody physics because Unity controls these itself based on the global timescale.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using rigidbody physics.

Comment: I want something like this: `GetComponent<Script>().Time.timeScale = 1` Is it possible?

Comment: @Fawq What you *would* need is `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().Time.timescale`. But Unity does not provide this. Likely because collisions between rigidbodies in different timescales is something the laws of Newtonian physics do not cover very well, because they do not happen in the real world.